# Outlook '10 hangs often, IMAP sync

Tags: microsoft-outlook, imap

We have 3 employees using IMAP to sync with their Desktop and Android Phones. Two are using 70% of their accounts storage, another is using 80%. They all have similar counts on folder structure, etc.

The employee with the 80% storage is constantly having Outlook freeze on them for up to 5 minutes at a time. I realize this is Outlook connecting and doing activity on the server, but no one else has this problem. In fact, one user with the 70% storage used uses a very slow laptop, and doesn't have freezing issues.

The network is the same, the settings are the same - at a loss how to proceed? Obviously "Outlook is a crummy IMAP client" doesn't help management...

Comment: Do they have any Kaspersky Anti-Virus add-ons installed. I've found that this can cause real problems with Outlook.

Comment: We do have Symantec Endpoint Protection, but all the clients have that